# Set div to the width of its containing text?

Tags: html, css, width

I have a div class `heading` that contains dynamically generated text, and I want to underline it using a `border-bottom`. But if I set `.heading {width:auto}` then the div horizontally fills its container, and the underline is way too long.

How can I make the div be only as long as the containing text?

http://jsfiddle.net/roLxsw3v/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [**Visual formatting model - 'Inline-block', non-replaced elements in normal flow:**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-width)
>
> If `width` is `auto`, the used value is the [shrink-to-fit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) width as for floating elements.
>
> A computed value of `auto` for `margin-left` or `margin-right` becomes a used value of `0`.

Therefore you could change the `display` of the element to `inline-block`.

In doing so, the element's width will ["shrink to fit"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) its contents, in this case the text.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cq0heLgr/)

```css
.heading {
    background: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">text</div>
```

It's also worth pointing out that you can omit `width: auto` since `auto` is already the default value.

Clearly, you could also change the element's type from a `div` to a `span`, which is `inline` by default.

Comment: can I just add value "inline" for the display?

Comment: @JeanGkol Yes, `inline` would also work. In some cases `inline-block` would be a more ideal option, though.

Comment: Hm, that's odd... the div is the proper width, but now `margin:auto` doesn't work to center the div: (http://jsfiddle.net/roLxsw3v/1/). Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @JoeMorano `margin: auto` will only horizontally center `block` level elements with a width. Ideally, you would add `text-align: center` to the parent element in order to center an `inline-block`/`inline` level element. http://jsfiddle.net/5jmnmvs5/

Comment: you need to add display:inline-block with it @JoeMorano as what Josh Crozier answer. I found it work